# Creating INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger to update HasChanged field in 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I've created a transform view that updates the master table with values from two different tables.

When doing this update, I need to change the 'HasChanged' value in all the tables for the affected records.

Ex: One row in the master table is updated with road name from one table and city name from another. The rows in the 2 tables that contained the new road name and city name must have their HasChanged value updated to 0 (from 1), as well as the master table.

For this I need to create a trigger. So far this is what I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Transform].[trItems_HasChanged] ON [Transform].[vItems_HasChanged]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

        CREATE TABLE #inserted
        (
                             Id BIGINT
        )
        CREATE TABLE #PostnummerBy
        (
                             Postnr BIGINT
        )
        CREATE TABLE #Vejstykke
        (
                             Id BIGINT
        )

        INSERT INTO #Inserted (Infohub_Id)
        SELECT Id FROM inserted

        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixInserted_Infohub_Id ON #Inserted (Infohub_Id)

                UPDATE 
                             InfohubStaging.Perfion.tMirror_Items 
                SET 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 0
                FROM
                             InfohubStaging.Perfion.tMirror_Items 
                             JOIN #Inserted i ON i.Infohub_Id = InfohubStaging.Perfion.tMirror_Items.Infohub_Id
                WHERE 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 1

                UPDATE 
                             InfohubStaging.Nav.tMirror_PimItem 
                SET 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 0
                FROM
                             InfohubStaging.Nav.tMirror_PimItem 
                             JOIN #Inserted i ON i.Infohub_Id = InfohubStaging.Nav.tMirror_PimItem.InfohubId
                WHERE 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 1

                UPDATE 
                             InfohubStaging.Ax.tMirror_Items_LiveUpdates  
                SET 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 0
                FROM
                             InfohubStaging.Ax.tMirror_Items_LiveUpdates 
                             JOIN #Inserted i ON i.Infohub_Id = InfohubStaging.Ax.tMirror_Items_LiveUpdates.Infohub_Id
                WHERE 
                             Infohub_HasChanged = 1

    END
```

I am unsure how to correctly go about this. I'm aware that 2 temp tables are created when doing an update trigger (the data before and after). Since the temp tables are non-indexable, I need to create an index for them. So I need to create 3 tables, one for each of the tables who need to have their HasChanged value updated.

My expected output from this has the HasChanged value updated in the Vejstykke, PostnummerBy and Master table.

Comment: Is there any real trouble you are trying to overcome? Right now it looks like fighting windmills.

Comment: why is your concern here ? the `inserted` and `deleted` are very slow ? Seriously the temp table and index in your trigger are redundant

Comment: Unless your view has a lot of large columns (e.g. 50+ VARCHAR cols) and you update a large number of records at once (more than 2,000) there is no need to create temp tables and indexes. It is slower this way. Note: above figures are ballpark estimates. If you are dealing with very large updates then it would make sense, but you need to test first.